# Is Mi Yodeya helpful?

Tags: torah-study, stackexchange

Does anyone here feel that this site is helpful? I do, but is it [Bitul Torah](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9C_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94)? Because you could always go look up the answer in a sefer and get more *schar* (reward).

Comment: Shouldn't this be on meta?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Not necessarily.

Answer (score 6):

For questions that you could look up in a book, and you know what book to look them up in, and you have access to that book, you should go look them up!

However, there are many questions and many people for which these conditions will not be met.

mi.yodeya is intended to be a tool for certain situations, not a replacement for regular Torah learning.

For examples of questions that I feel are some good examples of the site being useful, please see the [Question of the Week](http://yodeya.blogspot.com/search/label/qotw) series (which has been on break for a little while) on lo.yodeya, our site news blog.

Comment: I think R. Isaac is right on. I have many misgivings about the internet but I have always tried to use it as a tool to find out <i>where</i> to find primary sources.

Answer (score 5):

I think its great it causes people to think of things they would not in the regular course of learning  and a community of some really well informed people is like having a chavrusah  so It is a win Win.

Answer (score 3):

My ancient Aramaic reading skills are exceedingly poor but I am able to understand concepts. I am not able to look things up in sefers and get schar but I am able to learn complex torah from the discussions of others on miyodea.