# Learning Halacha

Tags: halacha, olam-haba-world-to-come

The Mishnah Berurah (155:3) states that one is obligated on a daily basis to learn halacha and the Gemara (Megillah 28b and Niddah 73a) says, "Whoever learns halachos is assured that he is destined for the World to Come…"

How many halachos does one have to learn per day?

Comment: Consider marking an answer correct on this related question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55493/8775.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant text of the Mishna Beurah states:

> חייב אדם ללמוד בכל יום תורה שבכתב שהוא תנ"ך ומשנה וגמרא ופוסקים ובעלי בתים שאינם לומדים רק ג' או ד' שעות ביום לא ילמדו בגמרא לחוד דבזה אינו יוצא אלא צריך שילמוד דוקא גם ספרי פוסקים כל אחד כפי השגתו [שו"ע יו"ד וש"ך שם]

The daily requirement referenced by the Mishna Berurah, is the statement in the Talmud (Kiddushin 30a, Avodah Zara 19b) which states that a person should trisect his studies daily (cf. Tosafot Kiddushin 30a s.v. Lo) into Scripture, Mishna, and Talmud:

> ושננתם לבניך? אל תקרי ושננתם אלא ושלשתם, לעולם ישלש אדם שנותיו, שליש במקרא, שליש במשנה, שליש בתלמוד. מי יודע כמה חיי? לא צריכא - ליומי

The Mishna Berurah is inserting the study of poskim into the lineup, possibly because today poskim are the equivalent on Mishnah and Talmud in the times of the Amoraim.

With the context of the Mishnah Berurah, we can fairly confidently suggest the amount necessary to study.

Rav Amram Gaon writes that the daily recitation of the Korban Tamid, the fifth chapter of tractate Zevahim, and the B'raita "R. Yishmael says: with thirteen methods the Torah is expounded...", is based on the aforementioned Talmudic passage. This is in turn referenced by Tosafot (Kiddushin 30a s.v. Lo and Tosafot R. Elhanan there). Accordingly, it is apparent that even a very small amount of study satisfies the daily requirement.

Although this does not give us a specific amount for the halakha portion, it suggests that very little would be necessary; probably not even two halakhot.

Comment: Care to explain yourselves hit and run downvoters?

Comment: +1 just to add that this Halacha applies to people who are learning 3 hours a day or less as seems to be indicated in the Hebrew

Comment: @user15464  See the MB's sources: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55493/8775. While the Derisha says that people who learn a little shouldn't just learn Talmud, he doesn't say that people who learn a lot are exempt from the study of practical halakha. Although he does reference the view of Rabbenu Tam, he doesn't clearly fully agree with it, and indeed, states that the main thing is the study of poskim, and doesn't limit that statement to people who only learn a little.